# How do I restart the ioloop in tornado when fetching twitter stream api?

Tags: python, twitter, tornado

I'm using TweetStream (https://github.com/joshmarshall/TweetStream), a tornado based twitter streaming module to monitor the stream api.

I would like to know how can I restart the fetch process if want to change the tracked words.

My current solution (not exactly a solution) is giving me some errors.

```
stream = tweetstream.TweetStream(configuration,ioloop=main_io_loop)

stream.fetch("/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track="+tornado.escape.url_escape(words), callback=callback)


def check_words():
    global words
    with open('words.txt') as file:
        newwords = file.read()
        if words != newwords:
            words = newwords
        try:
            print newwords
            stream.fetch("/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track="+tornado.escape.url_escape(words), callback=callback)
        except:
            pass
        file.close()

interval_ms = 1000*10
scheduler = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(check_words,interval_ms,io_loop = main_io_loop)
scheduler.start()
main_io_loop.start()
```

Here is the error i'm getting

```
ERROR:root:Uncaught exception, closing connection.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/observrenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 305, in wrapper
    callback(*args)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/observrenv/src/tweetstream/tweetstream.py", line 155, in on_connect
    self._twitter_stream.read_until("\r\n\r\n", self.on_headers)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/observrenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 151, in read_until
    self._set_read_callback(callback)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/observrenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 369, in _set_read_callback
    assert not self._read_callback, "Already reading"
AssertionError: Already reading
ERROR:root:Exception in callback <tornado.stack_context._StackContextWrapper object at 0x2415cb0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/observrenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 421, in _run_callback
    callback()
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/observrenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 305, in wrapper
    callback(*args)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/observrenv/src/tweetstream/tweetstream.py", line 155, in on_connect
    self._twitter_stream.read_until("\r\n\r\n", self.on_headers)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/observrenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 151, in read_until
    self._set_read_callback(callback)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/observrenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 369, in _set_read_callback
    assert not self._read_callback, "Already reading"
AssertionError: Already reading
```

I achieved better results (no the best) by starting the ioloop again when calling check_words.

```
stream = tweetstream.TweetStream(configuration,ioloop=main_io_loop)

stream.fetch("/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track="+tornado.escape.url_escape(words), callback=callback)


def check_words():
    global words, stream
    with open('words.txt') as file:
        newwords = file.read()
    if words != newwords:
        words = newwords
        print newwords
        try:
            stream = tweetstream.TweetStream(configuration,ioloop=main_io_loop)
            stream.fetch("/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track="+tornado.escape.url_escape(words), callback=callback)
            interval_ms = 1000*10
            scheduler = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(check_words,interval_ms,io_loop = main_io_loop)
            scheduler.start()
            main_io_loop.start()
        except:
            pass
        file.close()


interval_ms = 1000*10
scheduler = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(check_words,interval_ms,io_loop = main_io_loop)
scheduler.start()
main_io_loop.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was said [here](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/921#comment-3478) by a twitter employee, the recommended is to do what I am already doing (but in a more moderated way). Just reconnect once a while if your query terms changed. Otherwise just keep the connection open. It's also important to monitor errors that twitter might send it to you or you might be banned.

Answer (score 0):

Looks, like you are missing main idea of Streaming API. 
Connection to it opened permanently.

```
stream = tweetstream.TweetStream(configuration,ioloop=main_io_loop)

#What you are doing in callback? 
stream.fetch("/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track="+tornado.escape.url_escape(words), callback=callback)


def check_words():
    #I guess, don't do it at all. 
    #global words
    #with open('words.txt') as file:
    #    newwords = file.read()
    #    if words != newwords:
    #        words = newwords
    #    try:
    #        #Don't open new stream here
    #        print newwords
    #    except:
    #        pass
    #    file.close()
    pass

interval_ms = 1000*10
scheduler = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(check_words,interval_ms,io_loop = main_io_loop)
scheduler.start()
main_io_loop.start()
```

By analizing your code, I think you just must do routine with new words in callback.

Comment: but if my needs changed (I need to monitor other words) how do I change that? If i'm monitoring "love" and then a user wants to monitor "hate", i believe I should change that fetch to "love,hate". I was thinking about stoping the io_loop and then start it over.

Comment: @gawry, best solution - stream "love,hate" and decide in your callback what word you have in stream. Pattern what you implemented above - will cause ban, because stream will aggressively reconnect. If for some reasons you have to monitor 2 words at one time, with one word per stream - use 2 threads. Yes, if you have changed words - restart thread.

Comment: So I believe I can just set the periodic call to a less frequent period to avoid being banned.